# connecting to local database xcode

Tags: php, sql, database, xcode, swift

Using MAMP, I have a database on phpMyAdmin and I want to be able to connect to it from my Xcode project. How would I make that connection my localhost? I'm confused as to how to connect to a PHP file that inserts into my database from Xcode as well. I plan to use swift for my Xcode project.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. You want to access to the database from XCode? Within a build script, I presume?

Comment: `from my Xcode project` Don't you mean *"from my app"*? `into my database from xcode` Don't you mean *from the app*?

Comment: @FredericP yes I want to access a database from Xcode. The problem is I'm not sure if it is possible to connect to a php file that will insert/find things in my database locally. I am using MAMP so I am using a localhost.

Comment: @EricD yes I mean "from my app"

Comment: But you're still answering `yes I want to access a database from Xcode` in the previous comment!! Please stop referring to "Xcode" instead of referring to your app, this is wrong and confusing. I suggest you [edit] your question and change the wording accordingly if you want answers. Thank you.

Comment: @EricD , because that's how he referred to it as well. So I continued in the same format. I don't want to change my wording if he understands what I'm talking about.

Comment: @EricD It's the same thing. I want to connect my app (which is on Xcode) to my database. I don't really understand why you're getting so upset about this. Anyways, I figured it out from other other questions.

Comment: Words have sense. You could want to connect a DB to *Xcode, the IDE*, as @FredericP asked in his first comment, for example for using with a build script for your app. But that is not what you want, you want to connect the DB *to your app*. The fact that you're telling me that it's the same is a big issue and you should be able to understand that. And I'm not upset: I'm frustrated to see someone that needs help being so stubborn that somehow they're refusing to help themselves...

Comment: @ Eric D, thanks for the life lesson.

Comment: Hi @OviyaArasu , I will appreciate if you can share the way you made the connection working as I am trying to do a similar project :)